# Backbone Fetch Related Models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working on a Backbone app, but everything I've read so far is either about displaying a list of items (a TODO list for example) or a single item.

Right now I have users, each user has a list of skills (pretty much like any game). I can easily get all users or a single user, the same for the skills but what if I want to get all the skills for a given user? How would I do that?

I thought about just adding a property to the users with a new instance of a collection, something like this:

```
var Users = Backbone.Model.extend({
  skills: new Skills({ user: this })
});

var Skills = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Skill,
  url: '/someUrl',
  initialize: function (options) {
    // fetch all skills from an user
    this.fetch({ data: { user: options.user.get('id') } });
  }
});
```

But I don't have much experience with Backbone and I don't really like the idea of that, also the request would look something like `/someUrl?user=1` which I'd rather avoid, `/someUrl/user/1` would be much better.

I've also noticed [BackboneRelational](http://backbonerelational.org/) but I haven't really tried it, it seems a bit of an overkill for my problem, but maybe I'm wrong.

What approach should I take to fetch all of my users skills? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you to checkout this [post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/), sure you will find an answer. If short you may have following approach without any additional plugins and build nested model :

expect following json:

```
{
   name: 'Gorbachov',
   age: '75',
   skills: [
       {
           name: 'kalashnikov'
       }, 
       {
           name: 'vodka'
       },
       {
           name: 'balalaika'
       }
   ]
}
```

lets update `User` model:

```
User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        var skills = this.get("skills");
        if (skills){
            this.skills = new Skills(skills);
            this.unset("skills");
        }
    }        
})
```

Then `create SkillsCollection`:

```
SkillsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Skill
})
```

and `Skill` model:

```
Skill = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'unnnamed'
    }
})
```

Comment: Oh! I see, that surely feels better. thanks a lot! I'll read the article and try to implement this.