# backbone.js parse JSON and set attribute as new collection

Tags: json, parsing, backbone.js

Is they a way to parse an attribute of a model as a new collection?

Im loading a large JSON file with various nested arrays and I want to parse the arrays into new collections contained inside each parent model.

Thanks,
G

Comment: Sure, checkout this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232982/backbone-fetch-related-models/25236715#25236715

Comment: Great stuff, thanks Evgeniy. (p.s <20secs to reply!!)